# How to trigger method in controller when element is clicked in view for Rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

The drop down list elements that I want to click on are

```
<select class="store-select">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Administrator</option>
  <option value="2">User</option>
  <option value="3">Editor</option>
</select>
```

And I want it to trigger an action in the controller based on the option that was clicked.  So one of the things I'm hoping to learn is how to access that value in the controller.  I also want to redirect the page after an option is clicked.  I'm able to redirect the page when other links are clicked in my view, but when I click on an element in the drop down list, it doesn't redirect.  It doesn't even go to the view for that method.  When an element in the drop down list is clicked it just stays on the current page.

```
def practice  # the redirect doesn't work in this method but works in others 
    # redirect_to "https://tosbourn.com"
    render "ibotta/show"
end
```

My application.js file looks as the following

```
$('.store-select').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : '/users',
    type : 'GET',
    data : { user_id: this.value },
    dataType:'script'
  });
})
```

My routes.rb file contains the following

```
get 'users' => 'smiths#practice'
```

Let me know if there is anything I'm missing that you want to know about this problem.  Thank you.

Comment: you want to redirect the page or you want to call server action on element change?

Comment: Redirect the page on element change.  I'm just trying to make any view show up because as it is now, the page stays the same when one of the elements in the drop down list is clicked.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ChrisWilson feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you?

Comment: I had to go to sleep, and won't be able to work on this again until tonight.  But I'll be sure to check out your answer then.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using ruby on rails then you can do this one short line for example: -

```
<%your_options = [['Please select', ''],['Administrator','1'],['User','2'],['Editor','3']]%>

<%= select_tag "store-selects", options_for_select(your_options),:onchange => "self.location='/users/'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value", class: "your_class" %>
```

and your routes should be

```
get 'users/:id' => 'smiths#practice'
```

thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You're answer worked perfect.  I selected it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Could you possibly link the Rails documentation for this?  Or somewhere where I could learn more about it.

Comment: @ChrisWilson this is just a simple jquery and i used it with html, you can learn jquery from anywhere i prefer here basic 
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVDV697uvHpavA3K_eWGQap

Answer (score 2):

As you want to redirect on drop down change you can follow this

Suppose your drop down is

```
<select name="select1" id="select1">
        <option value="0">Page1</option>
        <option value="1">Page2</option>
        <option value="2">Page3</option>
        <option value="3">Page4</option>
    </select>
```

and your java script change event is

```
$select1.on( 'change', function() {
  switch(this.value){
    case '0':
      window.location = [page1url];
        break;
      case '1':
      window.location = [page2url];
        break;
      case '2':
      window.location = [page3url];
        break;
      case '3':
      window.location = [page4url];
        break;
  }  
});
```

you will redirect to urls you want on change